# Implementation of vector of integers with overloaded operators, fails to run properly

Tags: c++

I have huge problems with making this code work properly. 
http://pastebin.com/Mi6gj188

There's an output from example program on the bottom. It simply crashes and doesn't deliver proper results too. It seems that none of the overloaded operators work as it should

Comment: You need to (1) make a [_testcase_](http://sscce.org) that is fewer than, say, 30 lines long, that demonstrates the _specific_ problem that you've narrowed things down to, and (2) post it inline in your question.

Comment: Try and narrow down the possible error part to a few lines of code. No one here is going to go over your entire code.

Comment: worked it out with my friend's assistance now, my destructors are invalid. been looking for solutions for 5 hours...

Comment: @Szarlej There nothing wrong with your destructor. The problem is that you didn't write a copy constructor, your assignment operator is seriously sub-optimal as well. In other words you didn't follow the **rule of three** (as you have been told already).

Answer (score 4):

You didn't write a copy constructor, or use RAII. As a result, every time your `vector` object is copied (and it is, *a lot*, because you make no use of references!!) your internal data pointer is copied, sharing it amongst multiple objects (each of which will attempt to `delete` it on destruction) causing a horrible bug.

Your book tells you about the **rule of three**, which you should now go ahead and work on following.

Comment: This answer was a bonus answer because the problem was so easy to spot. In general, we shall not answer questions like this unless you narrow down the problem yourself with some debugging.